# Is there a Dispose Pattern in Python?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable

I have to create a python-wrapper for a C API. I have used `ctypes` to call into C dlls from python. I am able to create Handle and use it from python. I am looking for Dispose pattern in Python similar to that of C#. Does there exist a Dispose pattern in python?

Comment: Do you mean *deconstructor* instead of *dispose pattern* and the _ _del_ _ method?

Answer (score 7):

Python has:

- `try ... finally`, which is equivalent to the similar construction in C#;
- the `with` statement, which is an analogue of `using(... = new ...())` in C#.

Note that, unlike C#, `with` statement accepts already constructed object, calls `__enter__` when entering and `__exit__` when exiting. I.e., the object is initialized in `__init__`, the resource is acquired in `__enter__` and disposed of in `__exit__`. Therefore, such an object can be used multiple times.

With `contextlib.closing`, it's possible to get closer to C#. Acquire the resource in `__init__` and dispose of it in the `close` method. `contextlib.closing` makes a wrapper which calls `close` in its `__exit__`.

In your case, you should make all preparations in `__init__`, acquire the actual handle in `__enter__`, and dispose of it in `__exit__`.